# ¿Cómo obtener los días de la semana en Java?

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy realizando un cálculo en base a ciertas fechas. Estoy tratando de obtener las fechas comprendidas dentro de una semana, es decir obtener la fecha del lunes al domingo de una semana: por ejemplo, se tiene la fecha 2021/07/09, ¿cómo puedo obtener la fecha del lunes de esa semana y la del domingo de la misma semana?
Actualmente estoy tratando de hacer eso, pero siempre me retorna 1 y 7; la idea es obtener la fecha del lunes y domingo de la fecha que se le pase.

```
    dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    
    fech = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    fech.set(2021, 6, 9);
    
    date_aux = fech.getTime();                     
            
    
    System.out.println("Fecha actual ==> " + dtf.format(date_aux));
    
    System.out.println("Esta semana");
    
    int firstDayWeek = fech.getMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int lastDayWeek = fech.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);        
    
    System.out.println("Primer dia de la semana ==> " + firstDayWeek);
    System.out.println("Ultimo dia de la semana ==> " + lastDayWeek);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando las constantes del Calendar: `Calendar.DATE_OF_WEEK` que trae el numero correspondiente al día de la semana según siendo `Calendar.SUNDAY`(domingo) = 1 y `Calendar.SATURDAY` = 7.

Hacemos lo siguiente:

1. Obtenemos la fecha de hoy y el número de la semana que le
   corresponde
2. Calculamos la fecha del lunes sumando la diferencia entre el numero
   del dia de semana del lunes con la de hoy. Este es un resultado
   negativo para ir hacia atrás.
3. Calculamos la fecha del domingo sumando la diferencia entre el
   sabado y el dia de hoy

```java
          
           Calendar hoy = Calendar.getInstance();
           Calendar lunes = Calendar.getInstance();
           Calendar domingo = Calendar.getInstance();
//         hoy.setFirstDayOfWeek(1);
           hoy.set(2021,6-1,9); // Fijamos la fecha para el 9/6/2021 (Calendar utiliza los meses en base a 0 por eso le restamos 1)
           lunes.set(2021,6-1,9);
           domingo.set(2021,6-1,9);

           int diaHoy = hoy.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // 
           if(diaHoy<hoy.getFirstDayOfWeek()) {
              diaHoy+=Calendar.SATURDAY;
           }
           lunes.add(Calendar.DATE,hoy.getFirstDayOfWeek() - diaHoy); 
           int ndias =  hoy.getFirstDayOfWeek() + Calendar.SATURDAY-diaHoy-1;  
           domingo.add(Calendar.DATE,ndias); // le sumamos ese dia
                   
           System.out.println("Hoy: " + hoy.get(Calendar.DATE)+" " + (hoy.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +" "+hoy.get(Calendar.YEAR)); 
           System.out.println("inicio de semana: " + lunes.get(Calendar.DATE)+" " + (lunes.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +" "+lunes.get(Calendar.YEAR));
           System.out.println("Ultimo dia de la semana: " + domingo.get(Calendar.DATE)+" " + (domingo.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +" "+domingo.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Resultado:
lunes: 7 6 2021
domingo: 13 6 2021

Comment: Cuando se encuentra por ejemplo en domingo, toma la semana siguiente

Comment: Gracias. Hice la corrección

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando `getMinimum()` y `getMaximum()` que siempre te retornarán un entero con el día de la semana sin más, pero en ningún caso estás seteando el calendario a esas fechas. Una forma de hacer lo que quieres sería seteando el calendario directamente al día lunes y domingo respectivamente, por ejemplo:

```
    fech.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, fech.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("Primer dia de la semana ==> " + fech.getTime());

    fech.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, fech.SUNDAY);
    System.out.println("Ultimo dia de la semana ==> " + fech.getTime());
```

**Salida:**

```
Primer dia de la semana ==> Mon Jul 05 23:56:00 CEST 2021
Ultimo dia de la semana ==> Sun Jul 11 23:56:00 CEST 2021
```

A partir de Java 8 te recomiendo usar [las clases de la API java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), que facilita enormemente el trabajo con fechas, períodos, etc.

Por ejemplo:

```
    LocalDate mDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 7, 9); 

    System.out.println("Primer dia de la semana ==> " +mDate.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    System.out.println("Último dia de la semana ==> " +mDate.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
```

Salida:

```
Primer dia de la semana ==> 2021-07-05
Último dia de la semana ==> 2021-07-11
```

Comment: En android esto me responde siempre 1 para domingo y 2 para lunes LUNES ==> 2021/08/02, DOMINGO ==> 2021/08/01